# Meaning of "Karma"

Tags: word-meaning, american-english

I know the meaning of this word is readily available on internet. But for a non-native speaker like me, its actually hard to get the meaning. Please could someone elaborate its meaning with the help of an example?

Comment: What part of the definition confuses you? It's not useful to just say "I read it but I didn't get it."

Answer (score 1):

**Karma** has a meaning of **energy** but also **fate**. When a person is **nice** people will say that person has

> **good karma**

Not only will **good things** happen to that person, they will also spread **good energy** to the world. It is reflective of the actions, manners, and general ***feeling*** one gets from an individual.  For example, stopping and **helping an elderly person** who is struggling to cross the street.

If someone does something **bad** or **evil**, it can be said they have

> **bad karma**

or the act will **bring bad karma** to them. That is, they will get **bad energy** or **bad things will happen** to them. For example, **drowning kittens**, will bring you bad karma.

In a Western sense, from my experience, karma is more a reference to the state in one's **current life or moment** and less about **reincarnation**. This is probably because reincarnation is less of a Western belief.  A similar phrase which is often used is:

> **What goes around, comes around**

even the old adage:

> **You are what you eat**

has this notion in mind of **action and reaction**.

**Karma** has a meaning which carries more weight than just **luck**. Having **good karma** is more than just having **good luck**, and having **bad karma** is worse than just having **bad luck**.

[ NB: this is purely from my Westernised perspective ]